# MAMP localhost not Responding

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

I am trying to run php file using MAMP on my mac system having maverick operating system. 
it was working good before but suddenly it stop responding.
when I run html file it work fine even when I run any .php file with out database PDO it work fine but when I try to run php file with PDO database connection, localhost does work.
any concrete suggestions. welcome !

```
<?php 

try
{    
   $host ="localhost";
   $db ="ijdb";
   $user="ijdbuser";
   $pwd = "ijdbuser";
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=$host; dbname = $db', $user, $pwd);
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}

catch (PDOException $e)
{
   $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
   include 'output.html.php';
   exit();
}

$output = 'Database connection established.';
include 'output.html.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons as to why it's failing.

1) [Variables do not get parsed in singles quotes](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single)
2) You have spaces; [there should not be any](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-parameters).

```
'mysql:host=$host; dbname = $db'
                //^      ^ ^
```

needs to read as:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db"
^                           ^
```

You may also want to use:

```
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
```

---

**Nota:**

You should also modify your `catch{...}` to read as:

```
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    print $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

to get the real reason as to why it's failing.